# JavaScript heap out of memory on Azure build

Tags: node.js, azure, aspnetboilerplate, ng-build

I' m using aspnetboilerplate with Angular and .NET Core. When i try to deploy application on Azure it shows:

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

This is my azure pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    npm run build-prod
    ng build --c=production 
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

and in the package.json file i' ve added the **build-prod** property.

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
    "hmr": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --hmr",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "lint": "tslint --force --project src/tsconfig.json src/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "build-prod": "node --max-old-space-size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
  },
```

Comment: What has been your question?

Answer (score 11):

Solution for Azure Pipeline in Azure DevOps:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Build
  env:
    NODE_OPTIONS: --max_old_space_size=16384
```

Set the Environment Variable `NODE_OPTIONS` with value `--max_old_space_size=16384` in your Build-Task.

Comment: For future seekers CI-newbies like me, this doesn't needs to be a powershell task. It can be your build task, you just need the env part on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the NODE_OPTIONS in the variables section of the yaml pipeline:

```
variables:
  NODE_OPTIONS: --max_old_space_size=4096
```

Comment: This was an easy solution that worked great in a non-YAML (classic) Pipeline.  I added it to the Pipeline's Variable table.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

pipeline.yml

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    npm run build-prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
    "hmr": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --hmr",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "lint": "tslint --force --project src/tsconfig.json src/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "build-prod": "node --max-old-space-size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=production"
  },
```

and the build will take about 30 minutes.. but this is another known problem

Comment: Any other solution you might found?

Comment: @C1X please explain your solution

Comment: @nlips He added --configuration=production to his build-prod script. Not sure how that's a solution. Maybe --max-old-space-size is ignored without?

Answer (score 1):

I manually trigger a deployment from the Azure extension in VS Code (rather than using the pipeline per other answers).  I had to increase the memory allocation in package.json as follows to resolve this issue:

`"build": "react-scripts build --max_old_space_size=16384"`

But I also had to scale up the Azure server to the next tier, with more RAM (i.e. the step above on its own did not resolve the problem, as there wasn't sufficient RAM on the server to be allocated).

Answer (score 0):

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Increase memory
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
          $env:NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
```

Comment: setting `--max_old_space_size` has been proposed in every answer so far.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.