# How to capture heap dump while running azure pipeline?

Tags: java, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am facing below OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error while running my pipeline. I have also tried to increase heap space to 4Gb but still getting same error.

```
 Caused by:
2023-07-24T10:16:10.8047611Z                     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2023-07-24T10:16:10.8047931Z                         at java.base/java.util.HashMap.newNode(HashMap.java:1901)
2023-07-24T10:16:10.8048271Z                         at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:629)
2023-07-24T10:16:10.8048622Z                         at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:514)
2023-07-24T10:16:10.8048969Z                         at java.base/java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:484)
```

Now, I am trying to capture heap dump to identify memory leak and root cause of out of memory issue.

Can someone please help me to capture heap dump ?

Comment: Hi, I added an answer to the question, i appreciate if you accept and upvote it if it address the solution otherwise feel free to leave comment, i will be glad if i could help

Comment: Please consider looking at the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509976/javascript-heap-out-of-memory-on-azure-build.  Also consider running your pipeline manually (e.g.  
 using the Azure extension in VS Code) so you can troubleshoot memory *BEFORE* the OOM crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

> How to capture heap dump while running azure pipeline ?

One practice is to using [jmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr014.html) command-line tool on running the pipeline to capture a heap dump in binary format and save it to a file (heapdumpreport.bin).
Replace the `PID` with the process ID of your Java application, the `sas-token`, `name-of-your-container` and `storage-account-name` tags with proper values.

```
- script: |
    jmap -dump:format=b,file=heapdumpreport.bin <PID>
    azcopy copy heapdumpreport.bin "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<name-of-your-container>/heapdumpreport.bin?sas-token"
  displayName: 'Heap Dump Report'
```

Which this script we used `azcopy` command  to upload the heap dump into your storage account using an SAS token.